# UIButton background image not changing on tap

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I've got an UIButton which I'm successfully setting the background image for. I want to change the background image when the user taps it (which navigates to the next view controller). Unfortunately, the background doesn't change for taps. However, it *does* change when I tap and hold the button so I'm pretty confused. Code looks like the following:

```
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x_offset, y_offset, width, BUTTON_HEIGHT)];
    [button setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    UIImage *buttonImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"main_button"]
                            resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10)];
    UIImage *pressedbuttonImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"main_button_pressed"]
                            resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10)];
    [button setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setBackgroundImage:pressedbuttonImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [button setBackgroundImage:pressedbuttonImage forState:UIControlStateApplication];
    [button setBackgroundImage:pressedbuttonImage forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
    [button setBackgroundImage:pressedbuttonImage forState:UIControlStateReserved];
    [button setBackgroundImage:pressedbuttonImage forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    return button;
```

I know I overdid it with the UIControlStates but I wanted to demo that I've tried them all :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is you are only changing the images when each event occurs. When you tap and hold it'll show the highlighted image. When you change that state it revert back to normal state and show the image (Normal background image)

You can achieve the desired behavior in two ways:

**1)**

In your `IBAction`, change the normal button image.

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)button
{
   UIImage *pressedbuttonImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"main_button_pressed"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10)];
   [button setBackgroundImage:pressedbuttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

**2)**

Set `selected` or `highlighted` property of button to `true`

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)button
{
   button.selected = YES;
}
```

Comment: Your first approach worked - although I had to write a handler for UIControlEventTouchDown and UIControlEventTouchUpOutside - the latter to reset the image if the user moves their finger off the button. Luckily I have a helper method that builds my buttons so I don't have to add these lines of code everywhere :)

Answer (score 0):

Well the issue is once you have stopped tapping the button, the button's background image is going to default to whatever background image you set for the UIControlStateNormal.  So what you need to do is when your button is tapped, reset the UIControlStateNormal background image to whatever image you want after selection of the button.

Comment: Are you saying it changes too quickly for me to see?

Comment: Did you find a solution for your problem because i am also having the same problem now. I also thinks it is changing to quickly and we cant see the change.